# Control GPIO without Device Tree configure on iMX.6

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

On old iMX.6 BSP without DT (Device Tree), GPIO is controlled by following code:

```
#define SABRESD_SHUTDOWN    IMX_GPIO_NR(4, 15)

gpio_request(SABRESD_SHUTDOWN, "shutdown");

gpio_direction_output(SABRESD_SHUTDOWN, 1);
gpio_set_value(SABRESD_SHUTDOWN, 0);

gpio_free(SABRESD_SHUTDOWN);
```

However on new BSP, I cannot use `IMX_GPIO_NR` anymore. Instead, `of_get_named_gpio` provides access to GPIO defined in DT. But it is a little complicated because our product never changes the GPIO ports.

My question is, is it possible to control GPIOs without DT definition (just using the old method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are using newer kernel, I would recommend you to port your code to support the latest features. Otherwise - why bothering upgrading the kernel if you are not willing to adapt to it?

Second, never say never.

[And finally](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-imx/hardware.h#L126):

```
#define IMX_GPIO_NR(bank, nr)           (((bank) - 1) * 32 + (nr))
```

Comment: Yeah, it woks! Thx